# Compile errors in Boost.Reflect with MSVC2013 and boost 1.55.0

Tags: boost, reflection

I've read about Boost.Reflect at http://bytemaster.github.io/boost_reflect/index.html and it seems like exactly what I need.  I've downloaded it from https://github.com/bytemaster/boost_reflect and found several incompatibilities with boost 1.55.0 and MSVC2013.  (E.g. Boost.Reflect uses the deprecated Boost.Signals, and it uses the "template" qualifier in ways that MSVC2013 treats as errors.)

I could go into details but my initial question is: is this supposed to work?  Github says that Boost.Reflect's last upgrade was two years ago.  Is it still being maintained?  Has it turned into something else?

Comment: Even actively supported Boost 1.55 libraries might not compile with MSVC12 (VisualStudio 2013), the more so Reflect, which is not a part of Boost and seems not to be actively maintained. So you'll probably have to patch it on your own.

Comment: Thanks.  Okay so I'll go ahead and add compiler workarounds to Boost.Reflect.

So that I don't have to fight on too many fronts at once, would you be able to suggest some reasonably recent versions of Boost proper and MSVC that are likely to be compatible with each other?  Then I can concentrate on the Boost.Reflect issues.

Comment: I believe the Boost trunk is already fine with msvc12, so you can either checkout the trunk (or wait for 1.56) or use 1.55 with an older compiler, like msvc10.

Comment: See the list of tested compilers [here](http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_55_0.html) (scroll the page down).